# Execution time difference in matrix multiplication caused by parentheses

Tags: numpy, python-3.6, parentheses

Given the two 1D `numpy` arrays `a` and `b` with

```
N = 100000
a = np.randn(N)
b = np.randn(N)
```

Why is there a considerable execution time difference between the following two expressions:

```
# expression 1
c = a @ a * b @ b

# expression 2
c = (a @ a) * (b @ b)
```

Using the `%timeit` magic of Jupyter Notebook I get the following results:

> %timeit a @ a * b @ b
>
> 223 µs ± 6.97 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

and

> %timeit (a @ a) * (b @ b)
>
> 17.4 µs ± 27.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both versions you do two dot products of length-N vectors. However, in addition the first solution performs N multiplications while the second solution only needs one.

`a @ a * b @ b` is equivalent to `((a @ a) * b) @ b` or

```
aa = a @ a  # N multiplications and additions -> scalar
aab = aa * b  # N multiplications -> vector
aabb = aab @ b  # N multiplications and additions -> scalar
```

`(a @ a) * (b @ b)` is equivalent to

```
aa = a @ a  # N multiplications and additions -> scalar
bb = b @ b  # N multiplications and additions -> scalar
aabb = aa * bb  # 1 multiplication -> scalar
```

The fact that matrix multiplication performance can depend on how to set the parentheses is well known. There exist algorithms to optimize [matrix chain multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication) by exploiting this fact.

Update: As I just learned, numpy has a function for optimizing multiple matrix multiplications: [`numpy.linalg.multidot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.multi_dot.html#numpy.linalg.multi_dot)